# Возможно ли получить точные img html-тэги из переменной через DOM

Tags: php, html

Необходимо получить из переменной точное значение всех `<img>` тэгов. В переменной их может быть несколько десятков и все разного вида, где-то просто `img src`, а где-то и с полным набором атрибутов, где-то может быть `<img .... />`, а где-то и просто `<img ...>`.
Хотелось бы сделать это без использования регулярных выражений и сторонних библиотек.
Пробовал так:

```
$content=new DOMDocument();
$content->loadHTML($htmlcontent);
$imgTags=$content->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgTags as $tag) {
echo $tag->nodeValue; }
```

Но почему-то результат не выводится. Хотя `$tag->nodeName` в этом цикле корректно выводит значение `img`. Пожалуйста, подскажите где у меня здесь ошибка или как можно решить задачу по-другому.

Необходимо получить именно точное целое значение, соответствующее `<img ...>` тэгу, а не какой-то из его атррибутов. Чтобы потом в зависимости от условий вырезать кусок этого текста из $htmlcontent или оставить.

Comment: Дело в том, что значение-то как раз пустое - <img... />. Вам нужны атрибуты. Копайте в сторону getAttributes для тэгов.

Comment: А, понятно. Это функция для XML, не понимает одинарные незакрытые тэги HTML?

Comment: Речь не о функции, а методе https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php public string getAttribute ( string $name )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Продублировал вопрос в англоязычном разделе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716701/is-it-possible-to-extract-full-accurate-image-tag-from-a-html-code-using-dom-in

Там ответили, что невозможно используя DOM получить точное неформатированное значение тэга, как мне это было надо. Но подсказали, что для удаления тэга в этом цикле можно использовать метод `removeChild`. То есть в моём случае:

```
$content=new DOMDocument();
$xmlEncodding = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$content->loadHTML($xmlEncodding.$htmlcontent, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imgTags=$content->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgTags as $tag) {

if $tag->getAttribute("src") == "fordel")
$tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);

}
echo str_replace($xmlEncodding,"",$content->saveHTML());
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз требуется сохранить структуру, то, возможно, пригодится библиотека PHP [Simple HTML DOM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) Она, вроде как не меняет структуру. Но, разумеется, лучше протестировать самостоятельно.

```
    <?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('test.html');

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { //выборка всех тегов img на странице
       echo $element->outertext()."\n";
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, это очень похоже именно на то, что мне надо, за исключением того, что такой способ форматирует структуру содержания тэга, то есть если было `<img      src="img">` (в этом куске между img и src - 5 пробелов, которые потом не сохраняются), то результат будет `<img src="img"/>`. Но мне важно точное, неформатирвоанное значение, соответствующее оригиналу. Неужели с помощью Document Object Model это сделать невозможно, и придётся использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: Придётся. Так как DOMDocument является парсером, который в том числе проводит нормализацию.

Comment: Добавил вариант - использование сторонней библиотеки.

Comment: Благодарю, за советы, они помогли мне найти оптимальное решение, которое подсказали в англоязычном разделе.

Comment: @federk Так делитесь же. И закрывайте вопрос.

Comment: Написал ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514675/205878 - с помощью метода `removeChild`... только вот не вижу где можно закрыть вопрос. Подскажите?

Answer (score -1):

А чем вам регулярки не нравятся-то? Как на счет:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $html, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $img) {
   echo $img;
}
```

Comment: В программе уже используется модель DOM для получения атрибутов тэгов, всё работает отлично - и хотелось бы вставить в имеющийся цикл одну единственную проверку, для которой нужно точное текстовое значение всего img тэга. Регулярные выражения, насколько я знаю, работают медленнее DOM, и для них, фактически, придётся писать отдельный обработчик.

Comment: @Kairat Jenishev <img src="http://wow!>" alt="А ведь и так можно!" >

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?